# Table Sorter Sorting not working in case of Ajax response data

Tags: jquery

I am trying to sort the data using the tablesorter .

The sorting works fine , if i dont use the Ajax call , this is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/abkNM/6740/

But if i use Ajax call , the sorting is not working

http://jsfiddle.net/abkNM/6742/

This is my code

**JQUERY**

```
function loadXMLDoc(value, index) {
    var difference = '100';
    var name = value;
    if (index == 1) {
        difference = '200';
    }
    var html = '<tr>\
                            <td class="text-center"><label for="' + name + '" class="marg_none"><div></div></label></td>\n\
                            <td>' + name + '</td>\n\
                            <td>' + difference + '</td>\n\
                           </tr>';
    $("#positivebody").append(html);
}
```

Could you please let me know how to resolve this .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/abkNM/6748/

```
function loadXMLDoc(value, index) {
    var name = value;
    var difference = '100';
    if (index == 1) {
        difference = '200';
    }
     $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/echo/html/',
         async:false,
        data: {
            title: value
        },
        success: function(data) {
        var html = '<tr>\
  <td class="text-center"><label for="' + name + '" class="marg_none"><div></div></label></td>\n\
                            <td>' + name + '</td>\n\
                            <td>' + difference + '</td>\n\
                           </tr>';

          $("#positivebody").append(html);  
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because your newly added table rows are added dynamically and your table sorter plugin is already initialized before.

So, you need to re initialize your table sorter plugin

```
$("#positivebody").append(html); // append new table rows
$("#myTable").
    .trigger('destroy') // first destroy your tablesorter 
    .tablesorter({}); // re-initialize it again
```

Alternatively, you can try,

```
$("#positivebody").append(html);     
 // set sorting column and direction, this will sort on the first and third column 
var sorting = [[2,1],[0,0]];     
$("#myTable")
      .trigger("update") // let the plugin know that we made a update 
      .trigger("sorton",[sorting]); // sort on the first column
```

Table Sorter [Ajax-Example](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-ajax.html)

Comment: Thanks , i kept your code , but i am not able to sort it .

Comment: Try my alternative option and see the demo Ajax-Example also

Comment: Could you please post a sample fiddle .

Comment: You can check this, http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-ajax.html. Also a fiddle is not possible because it will not allow to use Ajax. But, you can use the above code in your project and I hope it will work definitely..

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `.tablesorter()` after triggering the AJAX calls but before they complete. What happens is something like the following:

1. .ajax(...) # row 1 fetching starts
2. .ajax(...) # row 2 fetching starts
3. .tablesorter()
4. row1 result arrives, calling row1's `success` handler that adds the row
5. row2 result arrives, calling row2's `success` handler that adds the row

Try to run `.tablesorter()` after the values arrive. Running on every `success` may be too much but it's up to you.

Comment: putting asyn false in ajax call resolved the issue .

Answer (score 0):

that is because html is not loaded through ajax when `.tablesorter({    });` is called.  You need to call the `tablesorter` after appending html in method `loadXMLDoc`.

```
$('#myTable').tablesorter({});
$("#positivebody").append(html);
```

Comment: I tried as you mentioned , but still its not sorting.Could you please let me a sample fiddle of your code .